# Process JavaScript-generated page in BHO

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, bho

I'm developing a `BHO` and need to process page content on `OnDocumentComplete` event.
But I found a problem - there are no page content at that moment, because it is generated later by `JavaScript`.

I was trying to call myself by using Navigate method with JavaScript function that must call me, but without any success.
I've searched by keywords [bho](/questions/tagged/bho), [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and found no useful results.

Thanks for any advices.

**EDIT1:**
Creating a new thread and passing into it pointer to `this` works fine in development environment, but cause crashes on real system.

**EDIT2:**
Today's workaround - IE tool-bar button `IOleCommandTarget::Exec` method calls page parsing code. But it requires user interaction.

**EDIT3:**
New workaround - in `FinalConstruct` I create my own **window**. If template search fails I create new **thread**, that sleeps some seconds and sends `WM_USER` message to that window. Window procedure calls page parser.

Comment: Today's solution is to start **new thread** and past to it pointer to self. Thread do small sleep and analyse page content again.

Comment: You are aware you can self-answer you're question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Yes, I know. But this is still not a solution - small workaround that doesn't work properly.

Comment: In that case add that worksround code to your question and explain why/when that doesn't work

Comment: @rene - done. Question fixed.

Comment: You can expose methods from your BHO to the page and then have JavaScript call them when it is done. Alternatively you can use `setTimeout` or add a `load` event handler to the page and call your JS code. You can also use mutation observers or any other JS tool to detect that the page load is done.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I already have this method exposed, but don't know how this `JavaSctript` must look like.

Comment: @Alexander what do you want to detect? The easiest thing to do is _not_ to spin a thread but to call that method in a simple `setTimeout` - or to hook on `XMLHttpRequest` and detect onload events.

Comment: I analysing page content for specific tags (edit fields and other inputs) and, in case of match to template, redirect browser to other predefined location.

Comment: Question fixed. EDIT3 added.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Great thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @rene Great thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the issue. Today's solution is to handle most of event that can be fired by IE:

```
BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CVIEBHO)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1071, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE,   CVIEBHO::OnDocumentComplete)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1071, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE,   CVIEBHO::OnDownloadComplete)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1071, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_ONQUIT,             CVIEBHO::OnQuit)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1071, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2,    CVIEBHO::BeforeNavigate2)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1071, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_NAVIGATECOMPLETE2,  CVIEBHO::NavigateComplete2)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1071, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_PROPERTYCHANGE,     CVIEBHO::PropertyChange)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1071, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_PROGRESSCHANGE,     CVIEBHO::ProgressChange)
END_SINK_MAP()
```

Inside of my code I check against the URL witch type of event may occur for the current page and do parsing inside this event handler.